# How to use Ajax pager in Drupal7

Tags: ajax, drupal-7, block, pager

I want to use ajax_pager in my block.
I've installed Libraries API and Ajax Pager API (as it described on the AP API page). But it's still not working.
When I use 'pager' instead of 'ajax_pager' it works.
What I'm doing wrong?

```
<?php
function latest_news_block_info() {    
    $blocks['latest_news_block'] = array(
    // info: The name of the block.
    'info' => t('Latest News'),
);

  return $blocks;
}

function latest_news_block_view($delta = '') {
    // The $delta parameter tells us which block is being requested.
    switch ($delta) {
        case 'latest_news_block':
        // Create your block content here
        $block['subject'] = t('Last news');

    $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
    //change news by the name of your content type
    $entities = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
        ->pager(5, 0)
        ->entityCondition('bundle', 'news')
        ->propertyOrderBy("created", "DESC")
        ->execute();

    $content = "";
    foreach($entities['node'] as $obj) {
         $node = node_load($obj->nid);
         $content .= "<img src='" .file_create_url($node->field_image['und'][0]['uri']) . "' width='200px' height='200px'>" .  l($node->title, "node/" . $node->nid) . truncate_utf8($node->body['und'][0]['value'], 200, true, true) . '<br><hr>';
         $block['content'] = $content;
    }

    break;
   }


   $pager = theme('ajax_pager', array('parameters' => array('selector' => 'block-system-main')));
   $block['content'] .= $pager;

   return $block;
}
```

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: Pager not showing